# Why result is 2, not 2.0?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    cout << 7/3*1.0 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Why result of 7/3*1.0 is 2, not 2.0?
1.0 is double.

Comment: Why should the floating point number 2 be displayed as 2.0?

Comment: `1.0` is a `double`, not `float`.

Comment: floating points have more than one digit after the `.`, why did you expect `2.0`, it could have been `2.00` or `2.000`, though `<<` displays it as `2`, because `2 == 2.0`

Comment: `double` and `float` are floating point number types, but "float numbers"

Comment: C++ does not output insignificant zeros by default.

Answer (score 3):

`1.0` is not a `float`, it's a `double`. If you want a float then you'll have to type this:

```
// f means float

1.f
1.0f
1.23455f
```

The reason why you are getting 2 as output, not 2.0 is that that's how `ostream` works. If you want the extra decimal places then you can do the following:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    std::cout.precision(1); // Display only up to 1 decimal place
    std::cout << std::fixed << 7 / 3 * 1.0 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

`std::fixed` just forces the viewing of decimals. For more info on this, click [here](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/fixed/).